# find values that do not belong in 2 tables using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of ChildProducts that has a column called ItemID that references a column called ItemID in a Products table.

I need to be able to quickly list all of the ItemID's in ChildItem's that do not exist in products.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM ChildItems
WHERE ItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM Products)
```

`NOT IN` or `EXISTS` will run faster than a `JOIN` for this since they both short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.ItemID 
from ChildProducts c left outer join Products p on c.ItemID = p.ItemID 
where p.ItemID IS NULL
```

EDIT: JNK's answer would be the best bet though, see it below.

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS Clause would get the job done:

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    ChildItems c
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM Products p WHERE p.ItemID = C.ItemID)
```

*Sorry - Syntax error made in haste when responding. Thanks @JNK.*

Comment: The `C.ItemID` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Fixed. After looking at it a second time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ChildItems c
WHERE   c.ItemID NOT IN(SELECT p.ItemID FROM Products p)
```

If you're looking to delete the orphaned records, you can do this:

```
DELETE FROM ChildItems c
WHERE  c.ItemID NOT IN (SELECT p.ItemID FROM Products p)
```

Here's another way you can find the orphaned records:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ChildItems c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products p
           ON c.ItemID = p.ItemID
WHERE    p.ItemID IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

Assuming that you're looking to eliminate this issue after removing the orphaned records, I would suggest adding a foreign key to the `ChildItems` table, and using a cascading delete when removing records are deleted from the `Products` table.

Comment: ...so now it's the same as my answer except posted 2 minutes later?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. One of many posts on this from the pros: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

Comment: Our answers are not identical. My answer gives two options, and an option for deleting the orphaned records. There are only a few ways to do the query, so obviously our answers would be similar.

Comment: James this was a really good short discussion why did you delete your comments?

Comment: @CodeMonkey12: Because I wanted my last comment to be visible to people viewing the page, because it was the most important of my comments. There are obviously some politics at work here, seeing as how we both posted correct answers and mine has been downvoted while his has been upvoted. There are 3 ways that I can think of to write the query - LEFT JOIN, NOT IN, and NOT EXISTS. Obviously, the answers will share some similarity. Whatever... it's really not that important.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the often forgotten `EXCEPT` operator to perform this anti semi join.

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM ChildItems
EXCEPT
SELECT ItemID 
FROM Products
```